# What is a SysferException and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, symantec

When starting the debugger, I get eight instances of the following:

> First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD59B16D in myprogram.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SysferException at memory location 0x000000000028D7B0.

All I have been able to find on it is that it is connected to Symantec and sysfer.dll.

Comment: It comes from the shrink-wrapped malware that programmers voluntarily install on their machine.  Well, not always voluntary, Symantec crap tends to be enforced by the Big Corporation.  If you can't uninstall it then just move on with your life, first-chance exceptions are not critical.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following instructions useful:

To prevent sysfer.dll from loading in the Visual Studio, use regedit to set the following registry to 4:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysPlant]
"Start"=dword:00000004
Reboot after changing the regedit.

[source](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/develop/devpartner_-_code_analysis/w/knowledge_base/18590.sysfer-dll-from-symantec-is-interrupting-the-functionality-needed-by-devpartner.aspx)